# Overriding Bootstrap in django-pipeline

Tags: css, django, twitter-bootstrap, django-pipeline

I have a Django application with which I am using the django-pipeline package and bootstrap.css:

```
PIPELINE_CSS = {
'myCSS': {
    'source_filenames': (
        'css/bootstrap.css',
        'css/bootstrapoverride.css',

    ),
    'output_filename': 'bootmin.css',
    'variant': 'datauri',
},
```

}

As you can see above I have included an additional file "bootstrapoverride.css" which I was hoping to use to override some features of Bootstrap, for instance in my override file:

```
.navbar {
min-height: 100px;
        }
```

So I thought this may work, but no override is happening, maybe this is not possible using pipeline.  I would like to avoid editing the bootstrap.css file directly.  Thank you for any insight here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this, but I would set your project up a bit differently. I would have a `vendor` bundle and and a separate `company` or `project` specific bundle.

An example would look something like this;

```
PIPELINE_CSS = {
'vendor': {
    'source_filenames': (
        'css/bootstrap.css',

    ),
    'output_filename': 'vendor.css',
    'variant': 'datauri',
},
'project': {
    'source_filenames': (
        'css/bootstrapoverride.css',

    ),
    'output_filename': 'project.css',
    'variant': 'datauri',
},
}
```

And then include them in this order in your `base.html` file:

```
{% stylesheet 'vendor' %}
{% stylesheet 'project' %}
```

Comment: @josephmisti Thank you for the reply, really good suggestion; however I am not seeing an override.  I noticed that in the console I am not seeing bootstrapoverride.css in a GET like the other assets.  Any thoughts on this?

Comment: This works, however for whatever reason I had to rename my project file from bootstrapoverride.css to "myAppStyleSheet.css" *or whatever you want to call it.  Not sure if there was some sort of collision with the "bootstrap" prefix, I do not know enough about how django-pipeline works.  Thank you Joseph

Comment: django-pipeline is pretty confusing but once you get the hang of it - it is much better than the alternatives (jammit,etc). no problem - give me an upvote :)